# Button Not Responding problem with async React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I copied fallowing code from a github project and tried  using expo. The project executed without error  but when i press button nothing happens. not even error this is my code 
NB- I stetted an alert inside onChooseImagePress  and alert is working fine

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Button, Text, View, Alert, } from 'react-native';
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {firebaseConfig} from "./ApiKeys";

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    onChooseImagePress = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
        //let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            this.uploadImage(result.uri, "test-image")
            .then(() => {
                Alert.alert("Success");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert(error);
            });
        }
    }

    uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + imageName);
        return ref.put(blob);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Choose image..." onPress={this.onChooseImagePress} />
            </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: { flex: 1, paddingTop: 50, alignItems: "center", },
    });
}
```

Comment: you have commented `launchImageLibraryAsync`. but actually that is working.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple syntactical issues in your code:

1. **const styles...** should be defined inside the render function currently its dangling outside the class
2. Brackets mismatch

```
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Choose image..." onPress={this.onChooseImagePress} />
            </View>
            );
        }
    } // the class ends here


Please let me know if it still doesn't work
```

Comment: You don't need to define `const styles` inside the render function. There is no benefit to doing it there. If you look at the [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style) in the docs it is  outside the class

Comment: what is the benefit of adding the styles inside render method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { }; 
    this.onChooseImagePress= this.onChooseImagePress.bind(this);

  } 

<Button title="Choose image..." onPress={() => this.onChooseImagePress()} />
```